# Jquery callback for for

Tags: jquery, for-loop, callback

Erhm - not sure about this one. But here goes :)

I want a callback when all the .instagram-placeholders have been added.
But where, and how?

```
success: function(data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
        $("#instaWrap").append("<div class='instagram-placeholder'><a target='_blank' href='" + data.data[i].link +"'><img class='instagram-image' src='" + data.data[i].images.thumbnail.url +"' /></a></div>");
        total += 1; 
    }; 
    $("#instaWrap").append('<div class="clear"></div>');
}
```

Thanks a bunch :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple answer would be:

```
success: function(data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.data.length; i++) {
        $("#instaWrap").append("<div class='instagram-placeholder'><a target='_blank' href='" + data.data[i].link +"'><img class='instagram-image' src='" + data.data[i].images.thumbnail.url +"' /></a></div>");
        total += 1; 
    }; 
    $("#instaWrap").append('<div class="clear"></div>');
    callback(); // just call the callback :)
}
```

But if you want to wait until all images are loaded, you can try this approach:

```
success: function(data) {
    imagesLoaded = 0;
    imagesToLoad = data.data.length;
    $.each(data.data, function() {
        // Create the elements:
        var el = $("<div class='instagram-placeholder'><a target='_blank' href='" + this.link +"'><img class='instagram-image' src='" + this.images.thumbnail.url +"' /></a></div>");
        // Bind load and error event of the image
        $('img', el).bind('load error', function() {
            if (++imagesLoaded == imagesToLoad) {
                callback(); // all images have been loaded
            }
        });
        // Append the element to the DOM
        $("#instaWrap").append(el);
        total += 1;
    });
    $("#instaWrap").append('<div class="clear"></div>');
}
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Really didn't think it was that simple :) 
And thanks for the extra solution :)

Comment: You should catch `error` events as well. If an image fails to load, you don't want to wait forever.

Answer (score 0):

Right way is use [JQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) or [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#each) each() methods to iterate all elements.

Answer (score 0):

As an addon to @WouterH:

Why don't you use the data-array to count the total number of items? What if *data* has only 28 items in it's list? You'll get errored.

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.count(); i++) { [...] }
```

Or, even a shorter version, you can try anything like:

```
$.each(data.data, function() {
    $("#instaWrap").append("<div class='instagram-placeholder'><a target='_blank' href='" + this.link +"'><img class='instagram-image' src='" + this.images.thumbnail.url +"' /></a></div>");
});
```

Code is written straight from brain -- It's an example. You can try anything like this.

Comment: That of course is true. I asume that the hardcoded value of 30 is there only as an example and doesn't exist in the real code.

Comment: BTW: guess it would be `data.data.length` instead of `data.count()`, no?

Comment: That's right, WouterH. I'm always into my own functions, where I am returning 'this.length;'. :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

the DOM is a synchronous API, so you don't need any callback: elements are added instantly.

Now, if you want to wait until all images are loaded, you can use the aptly named `load` event:

```
success: function(data) {
  var total = 0,
      loading = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
    var img = $(<img>).addClass('instagram-image').attr('src', data.data[i].images.thumbnail.url);

    img.on('load error', function() {
      loading -= 1;

      if(loading === 0)
        allImagesLoaded();
    });

    $("#instaWrap").append(
      $('<div>').addClass('instagram-placeholder').append(
        $('<a>').attr('target', '_blank').attr('href', data.data[i].link).append(
          img
        )
      )
    );

    total += 1;
    loading += 1;
  }; 

  $("#instaWrap").append('<div class="clear"></div>');
}
```

However, as [jQuery's doc](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) says:

> Caveats of the load event when used with images
>
> A common challenge developers attempt to solve using the .load()
> shortcut is to execute a function when an image (or collection of
> images) have completely loaded. There are several known caveats with
> this that should be noted. These are:
>
> - It doesn't work consistently nor reliably cross-browser.
> - It doesn't fire correctly in WebKit if the image src is set to the same src as before
> - It doesn't correctly bubble up the DOM tree
> - Can cease to fire for images that already live in the browser's cache